# how to open dsp file in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual studio 2008 and I wanted to open a .dsp file in Visual Studio.
This .dsp file is one of the source code of guitarix software. 
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue ?
I am getting this error[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHiQW.png)

Comment: Please inline the error message here, if you would like greater participation in your question

Comment: The extension .dsp was used for a project file for VS, back in the previous century.  But this project never once got close to VS and a .dsp file is actually a script for guitarix.  VS does not know that.  You have to use a text editor.  Actually using VS to build guitarix, well, good luck with that.

Comment: @HansPassant , Thank you for reply. 
So, what did they use to write Guitarix? Faust ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dsp files in guitarix are Faust (0.9.73) source files. So you could open them with any text editor.